# No interpretar código html en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Tengo un apartado donde se crea un texto y se puede visualizar los resultados, pero si digamos en el contenido del texto escribo código html y lo guardo, al momento de visualizar se está interpretando ese codigo html, pero no quiero eso.

para esto presento el siguiente ejemplo donde hay un texto en mensaje que contiene etiquetas html

Debería mirarse los resultados del siguiente modo con respecto a la propiedad Mensaje(ya que es la unica que va a contener codigo html)

[image: Como debería ser la propiedad mensaje]

pero el resultado es el siguiente

[image: Como se está ejecutando en realidad la propiedad mensaje]

se interpreta las etiquetas br b

el codigo para el mensaje en la primera imagen es

```
<div class="col">
  <label class="label">
    {{ "MODULES.GENERAL.INTERNACIONALIZACION.LABELS.MENSAJE" | translate }}:
  </label>
  {{
    form?.controls?.mensaje?.value !== "" &&
    form?.controls?.mensaje?.value !== null
      ? form?.controls?.mensaje?.value
      : ("CRUD_MESSAGES.NOT_REGISTERED" | translate)
  }}
</div>
```

es un codigo que va directamente escrito en el html, funciona bien, no interpreta el contenido de las propiedades como codigo html si llegan a tener, pero para el mensaje en la segunda imagen, se hace a traves de typescript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el confirm.show interpreta codigo html ya que como se puede ver se maneja etiquetas 
 , pero quiero que no interprete a row.mensaje como codigo html si este llega a tener, ya que en el ejemplo que mostré, el mensaje contiene etiquetas html y eso hace que aparezca con negrilla y espacio superior la frase name of the module...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se pudo solucionar a través del uso de "entidades de caracteres", lo cual prácticamente son referencias a un carácter y se representa con una sintaxis especial.
Entonces para solucionarlo utilicé el siguiente código

```
if (row?.mensaje?.includes('<') && row?.mensaje?.includes('>')) {
  row.mensaje = row?.mensaje.replace(/</gi, '&lt;');
  row.mensaje = row?.mensaje.replace(/>/gi, '&gt;');
}
```

este pedazo de codigo antes del this.confirm.show, lo que hace ese codigo es verificar si existen etiquetas html y como sabemos eso pues porque presentan <>, entonces lo siguiente es reemplazar todos los "<" por `lt;` y analogamente para ">"; lo que es `&lt;` y `&lt;` practicamente son lo mismos < > pero en una sintaxis especial que hace que no se interpreten como html.